# Task scheduler dependency using XML

Tags: xml

I need to rum two batch files one at 4:00 AM and another one at 6:00 AM,But while  starting the second task it should verify that the first task is  completed,If not completed it should wait for the first one to complete.The verification and time keeping should work simultaneously.  How is this achieved?. Some one help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get how this is related to XML.

One of the solutions you may use is following: sync on file system object.

I.e. :

1. your batch process 1 (p1) creates some file system file at 4:00, say p1.pid
2. when p1 finishes, it deletes p1.pid
3. also, when it finishes, it checks time. If time < 6:00, then end
4. if time > 6:00 then start p2

and your p2 launches at 6:00 :

1. p2 check that p1.pid exists
2. if yes -> end
3. if no -> start processing p2